# How can I declare a public function in an ES6 class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to add a public function inside a React ES6 class extended React.Component. However, nothing I've tried makes the function publicly available to other components.

Any tips are welcome.

Here's some examples of what I've tried:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react'
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent'

export class ArticleModal extends React.Component<void, Props, void> {
  static propTypes = {
  };
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
  }
  static privateMethod () {
    // This doesn't work
  }
  set privateMethod2 () {
    // This doesn't work either
  }
  privateMethod3 () {
    // ...and neither does this.
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <p>Some content</p>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
})
export default connect((mapStateToProps), {
})(ArticleModal)
```

Comment: can you see the correct `.render()` ?

Comment: Yes, it renders fine, just when I try to call any of the private methods I get the error.

`Uncaught TypeError: this._component.privateMethod is not a function`

I bind the `this._component` and it seems fine, I get methods from React and Redux, and I see that it's the correct component stored in the `this._component` variable.

Comment: `.privateMethod3` should have the same "reachability" as `.render`; i don't get how only one works...

Comment: Ahh, now I understand what you mean. No, I cannot see the render method, but the component does render. And it did help me solve it just now I think.

The answer was to access the 'renderedElement' from the component, in there I found a 'type' object which referenced the class with the methods available. This **does** feel like a bad solution though, like I'm just accessing the class rather than the instance.

Comment: I didn't manage to find a solution, accessing the renderedElement.type was just (as expected) the class and not the instance. However, the way I went around it was building another redux sub-store and used that as the intermediary between the components.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? React components are not designed to expose methods to others parts of the application; that's not their purpose. Only the component itself should call its own methods. If something needs to be invoked by another component, then the function gets passed along as a prop. But there should be no sense of "public" methods.

Comment: You're missing the code that is attempting to call these methods. That would help out a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your constructor like this

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.privateMethod3 = this.privateMethod3.bind(this);
}
```

and then try to call privateMethod3

Comment: that should not be needed, since `this` inside the constructor is presumably correct...

Comment: This doesn't make any difference, unfortunately. I should have made my question more precise and explain I had tried this already, apologies.